# Query to find all specific element in some dates

Tags: sql, entity-framework

My table has several **CardID** and I am looking for a query to read all **CardID** their **Date** for example less or equal to 20/10/16 (<= 20/10/16)

this my table but She will be with a lot more CardID, Here for example it should return only the CardID - 987654

[image: my table]

Comment: `Where Date  <= '2016-10-20'`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: `Where Date <= '2016-10-20'` will give my 123456 also, but I want CardID that is last record of Date is <= 20/10/16